# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo X1 Yoga Gen6

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lenovo, oem

I just received a new Lenovo X1 Yoga Gen6 (with Ubuntu preinstalled) and have tried to install:

1. Debian: Here I was never able to get past the Grub command line
2. Ubuntu: I was able to boot the latest LTS image from USB, however the OEM install was always launched directly without any option to perform a manual install.

The main reason for the effort is to enable Full Disk Encryption. And if possible to continue to use Debian as my personal OS.

Can anybody provide me with a hint to what is going on or how to change this behavior?

BTW I tried to install both distros with several USB sticks and all kinds of settings en- & disabled in the BIOS (Secure Boot, Security Chip etc.)

Comment: As this question is about Debian, you may get a more accurate answer [from the Debian User Forums](https://forums.debian.net/). While Ubuntu is based on the OS, Debian is not supported on this site 

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However it was not only about Debian, but rather generally about creating bootable sticks for a UEFI-only setup (see [the answer on the lenovo support forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/2734/5130601/5577866)). And the, at least to my understanding, weird behavior with the Ubuntu stick created with `dd` going directly into OEM install was one of the reasons I chose to post my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now I had always been using `dd` for creating bootable usb sticks, so I think I missed two things:

- Creating an unpartitioned FAT32 stick
- Extracting the iso directly to the stick (at least for me this was necessary)

If somebody has the same problem, here's what I did exactly (all on Ubuntu 20):

- Download the Ubuntu Desktop image
- Plug in USB stick
- Open "Disks"
- Select the USB stick on the left
- Click on the menu on the top right and select "Format Disk"
- Select the partition option "No partitioning (empty)" and click on "Format"
- Click on the gear icon below the volumes visualization and click on "Format Partition"
- Set a volume name and select FAT format, click on "Next" and confirm
- Then follow the instructions at https://techbit.ca/2018/09/creating-a-bootable-ubuntu-uefi-usb-drive/#creating-the-uefi-bootable-usb

---

*This answer was originally posted in the corresponding Lenovo forum thread (mentioning Debian there, but I tried both Debian and Ubuntu):
https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/2734/5130601/5577866*

Comment: Link only answers are not considered to be answers. What happens if later this link does not work? If the information is good add it to the answer you posted. You can still have the link but have the info as well.

Comment: @David Makes sense, I pasted the contents of the original answer. Thank you!